# How to ck if lubuntu is still installing

Tags: system-installation

How to check if install is still happening? Screen went black. I'm installing 18.04.4 via USB memory stick onto an old laptop (Dell Inspiron 1100 with 1GB ram, 40GB HD,32-bit). It's been going for 2hours now. I was getting a screen telling me it was copying files, but that screen went to black about an hour and a half ago. Is it waiting for me to do something? Disk light occasionally blinks.

Comment: The problem here is 1GB ram. It may be filled in 100% and then system hang without swap. Even with Lubuntu it will not be a pleasure to run Ubuntu on such hardware. Try to buy more RAM or switch to super small Linux distro like [antiX](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=antix).

Comment: Thanks Norbert. So I guess what you’re saying, in response to my question, is that there's no way to check if the install is continuing. The reason I'm trying lubuntu on my old system is that I'm simply trying to put new life back into it - it was running Win XP just fine before I nuked it installing lubuntu. And BTW: 18.04.4 finally brought up a screen that it said it completed it's install (after 2.5 hours). I'm now installing some more updates... cheers, jt

Comment: Also, I would love to add more ram, except I haven't been able to locate any with the right number of pins (2.5 V DDR SODIMM). jt

Comment: Having said that, I just did a search and found DDR2 & 4, with 1, 2, 4GB mem modules with 200 pins, but only 1.8v. Fires time in years that I've looked... Used to be 512MB was the biggest available. Will have to get some of the bigger ones and give them a try! cheers, jt